# How to change the generated file name in EF Power tools beta 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

How can I change the file name being generated by EF Power tools beta 2. I made some changes to EF.Utility.CS.ttinculde, Context.tt, Entity.tt and Mapping.tt files to match my desired naming convention. For example if my table name is 'project_site' then the generated type will be 'ProjectSite'.

The problem I am having is the name of the file will still be project_site.cs but I want it to be ProjectSite.cs. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share a link to some of the source of the .tt files?